Create custom order function with Solidity
How will i create function/s for sell stop, sell limit, buy stop, buy limit orders with 1% difference from market price with Solidity ? Percentage difference from market price feature will be must in that function. Give me a reply.
Expecting an error free code.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

StackOverflow is a website for programmers. It is not a website for hiring programming help. I suggest you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask but it is unlikely nobody can help you with open ended questions without good context why are you asking it and what are your goals.
